# Qual a forma correta de se abreviar "quantidade"?

Tags: abreviações

Existe alguma maneira correta de se abreviar "quantidade", em comparação com outras formas? Sempre alternei entre **qtd.** e **qtde.**. De acordo com este [post](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/abreviacao-de-quantidade/) no Dicio, no entanto, a abreviação correta seria **quant.**, uma forma com a qual sinceramente nunca topei.

As definições da palavra no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/quantidade) e no [Aulete](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/abreviacao-de-quantidade/) não fazem menção à uma forma abreviada. A definição desta abreviação é formalizada em algum documento? Além disso, há alguma menção sobre o uso *forçado* de tal abreviação (i.e., tornando as outras formas gramaticalmente incorretas de serem aplicadas)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É muito comum vermos os termos **qtd** ou **qtde** em livros, [código de programação](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GOAw0Lsdl-QC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22qtde%22&source=bl&ots=74UPVhTva7&sig=ACfU3U04GVGopIdtVgVVvYzD90NjVk-KjQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjol6DUqdXtAhWOF7kGHViTDW8Q6AEwD3oECBcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22qtde%22&f=false) e até mesmo em [documentos governamentais](https://www.gov.br/cidadania/pt-br/acoes-e-programas/inclusao-produtiva-rural/paa/paa-ci/resultados-das-chamadas-publicas/AnexoAB.pdf); no entanto, a grafia correta, de acordo com a [Academia Brasileira de Letras](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes), é **quant.** em todas suas formas:

- adv. quant. = advérbio de quantidade
- quant. = quantidade
- q.b. = quantidade bastante (usado em receitas médicas)

Obviamente, você pode usar *qtd* ou *qtde* visto que são mais conhecidas; para documentos formais, no entanto, prevalece o uso da norma culta, ou seja, *quant.*

Comment: Acho interessante notar que em https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_abreviaturas é possível encontrar mais abreviações relacionadas a “quantidade”; por exemplo, “q.b.”, significante de “quantidade bastante”.